# JavaFX - Animation around border

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to get an animation around a `Node` somewhat like the following:

[Ideal Effect](https://zippy.gfycat.com/GoodMatureApatosaur.webm)

Notice how the border is making a circling effect around the image -- this is the effect that I want to get on my JavaFX `Node`. How could something like this be done?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to create an image (with transparency) representing the rotating border, and just add it to the scene graph. Then use a `RotateTransition` to animate it.

Answer (score 0):

**I**)First method:

You can do that with 1 Node as following :

**1**-For shapes :

Use a `Path` which contains six `ArcTo` to form your three circles (4/2 for small circles) and (2 for the big one). but it will be difficult (**but possible**) to calculate the position of the two circle each time Using trigonometry.

**2**-For the effect :

You can use the [Bloom effect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/effect-types.htm) to perform that.

**3**-for the animation :

As said before some knowledge in trigonometry are required to create the rotation of your two circles relying on the **JavaFX animation system**.

**II**)Second method :

You can ignore the 1st step of the 1st method and create basically 3 circles directly and continue with the same process as the remaining two.